# Merge two dataframes using multiple substring matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
substring_ref = pd.DataFrame({"keyword_1":["Amazon Web Service -", "Virtual Apps"],  "keyword_2": ["","Service"],  "type": ["IaaS","PaaS"]})

sales = pd.DataFrame({"product_name":["Amazon Web Service - Automation", "Web", "Citrix Virtual Apps Premium OnPrem", "Citrix Virtual Apps Premium Service"], "Value":[10, 90, 500, 340]})
```

I have two dataframes that I want to merge based on either keyword_1 (if only one keyword is present) OR keyword_1 & keyword_2 both being present in the product_name field of the sales dataframe.

The end result should be this:

| keyword_1 | keyword_2 | type | product_name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon Web Service - |  | IaaS | Amazon Web Service - Automation | 10 |
|  |  |  | Web | 90 |
|  |  |  | Citrix Virtual Apps Premium OnPrem | 500 |
| Virtual Apps | Service | PaaS | Citrix Virtual Apps Premium Service | 340 |

Comment: Why row 3 'keyword_1' column is empty?.

Comment: The substring_ref dataframe only has two rows. Row 3 in the result table is empty because none of the keyword combinations in substring_ref are contained in the product_name field in the sales dataframe.

Comment: keyword 1 - > `Virtual Apps` is present in row 3 also

Comment: True, but since the word 'Service' (keyword_2) is not also in the product_name there should be no merge.  :)